# How to create PDF containing Persian(Farsi) text with reportlab, rtl and bidi in python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, reportlab, persian, farsi

I've been trying to create a PDF file from content that can be English, Persian, digits or a combination of them.

there is some problems with Persian texts like: "این یک متن فارسی است"

۱- the text must be written from right to left

2- there is a difference between characters in different positions in the word (meaning that characters change their shape according to their surrounding characters)

3- because the sentence is read from right to left then the normal textwrap doesn't work correctly.

Comment: if your app in an online app , try to use libraries which done this on php , because that's no matter for you to build pdf from python or any other language. if it's correct, aware me to post is as an answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I could create the PDF in python and so far it looks right but I haven't tested it with all different text styles. If you checked my code and find any problem, I would appreciate you to inform me.

Answer (score 11):

I used reportlab for creating PDf but unfortunately reportlab doesn't support Arabic and Persian alphabet so I used 'rtl' library by Vahid Mardani and 'pybidi' library by Meir Kriheli to make the text look right in PDF result.

first we need to add a font that supports Persian to reportlab:

1. in ubuntu 14.04:

   ```
   copy Bahij-Nazanin-Regular.ttf into
   /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/reportlab/fonts folder
   ```
2. add font and styles to reportlab:

   ```
   from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_RIGHT
   from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
   from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
   pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Persian', 'Bahij-Nazanin-Regular.ttf'))
   styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
   styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Right', alignment=TA_RIGHT, fontName='Persian', fontSize=10))
   ```

in next step we need to reshape Persian text Letters to the right shape and make the direction of each word from right to left:

```
    from bidi.algorithm import get_display
    from rtl import reshaper
    import textwrap

    def get_farsi_text(text):
        if reshaper.has_arabic_letters(text):
          words = text.split()
          reshaped_words = []
          for word in words:
            if reshaper.has_arabic_letters(word):
              # for reshaping and concating words
              reshaped_text = reshaper.reshape(word)
              # for right to left    
              bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
              reshaped_words.append(bidi_text)
            else:
              reshaped_words.append(word)
          reshaped_words.reverse()
         return ' '.join(reshaped_words)
        return text
```

and for adding bullet or wrapping the text we could use following function:

```
    def get_farsi_bulleted_text(text, wrap_length=None):
       farsi_text = get_farsi_text(text)
       if wrap_length:
           line_list = textwrap.wrap(farsi_text, wrap_length)
           line_list.reverse()
           line_list[0] = '{} &#x02022;'.format(line_list[0])
           farsi_text = '<br/>'.join(line_list)
           return '<font>%s</font>' % farsi_text
       return '<font>%s &#x02022;</font>' % farsi_text
```

for testing the code we can write:

```
    from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
    from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph
    from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle

    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("farsi_wrap.pdf", pagesize=letter,    rightMargin=72, leftMargin=72, topMargin=72,
                    bottomMargin=18)
    Story = []

    text = 'شاید هنوز اندروید نوقا برای تمام گوشی‌های اندرویدی عرضه نشده باشد، ولی اگر صاحب یکی از گوشی‌های نکسوس یا پیک' \
   'سل باشید احتمالا تا الان زمان نسبتا زیادی را با آخرین نسخه‌ی اندروید سپری کرده‌اید. اگر در کار با اندروید نوقا' \
   ' دچار مشکل شده‌اید، با دیجی‌کالا مگ همراه باشید تا با هم برخی از رایج‌ترین مشکلات گزارش شده و راه حل آن‌ها را' \
   ' بررسی کنیم. البته از بسیاری از این روش‌ها در سایر نسخه‌های اندروید هم می‌توانید استفاده کنید. اندروید برخلاف iOS ' \
   'روی گستره‌ی وسیعی از گوشی‌ها با پوسته‌ها و اپلیکیشن‌های اضافی متنوع نصب می‌شود. بنابراین تجویز یک نسخه‌ی مشترک برا' \
   'ی حل مشکلات آن کار چندان ساده‌ای نیست. با این حال برخی روش‌های عمومی وجود دارد که بهتر است پیش از هر چیز آن‌ها را' \
   ' بیازمایید.'
    tw = get_farsi_bulleted_text(text, wrap_length=120)
    p = Paragraph(tw, styles['Right'])
    Story.append(p)
    doc.build(Story)
```

Comment: Does this also work when mixing text directions, either with LTR words ("English" ) inside predominantly Farsi text, or the other way around?

Comment: It works fine with mixed sentences (having both Persian and English) and shows it from right to left.

Comment: @r.aj, Thanks for adding a full sample in details. When i tried the above sample the arabic words displayed in LTR direction "أختبار الرياضة" displayed as "ة ض اي رلا راب ت خ أ". Any suggestions ?

Comment: hi, I tried your text with this script and it worked properly. are you sure you used get_farsi_text or get_farsi_bulleted_text functions. because it seems that your text didn't go through  these:                                                            # for reshaping and concating words: #
              reshaped_text = reshaper.reshape(word)
              # for right to left: #    
              bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
              reshaped_words.append(bidi_text)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, although it works for me, lines are written in pdf from last to first, even your example.

Answer (score 7):

After working for a while with Reportlab, we had some problems with organizing and formatting it. It took a lot of time and was kind of complicated.
So we decided to work with pdfkit and jinja2. This way we can format and organize in html and CSS and we don't need to reformat Persian text too.

first we can design an html template file like the one below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head lang="fa-IR">
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body >
            <p dir="rtl">سوابق کاری</p>
            <ul dir="rtl">
                {% for experience in experiences %}
                <li><a href="{{ experience.url }}">{{ experience.title }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </body>
        </html>
```

and then we use jinja2 library to render our data into Template, and then use pdfkit to create a pdf from render result:

```
    from jinja2 import Template
    from pdfkit import pdfkit

    sample_data = [{'url': 'http://www.google.com/', 'title': 'گوگل'},
                   {'url': 'http://www.yahoo.com/fa/', 'title': 'یاهو'},
                   {'url': 'http://www.amazon.com/', 'title': 'آمازون'}]

    with open('template.html', 'r') as template_file:
        template_str = template_file.read()
        template = Template(template_str)
        resume_str = template.render({'experiences': sample_data})

        options = {'encoding': "UTF-8", 'quiet': ''}
        bytes_array = pdfkit.PDFKit(resume_str, 'string', options=options).to_pdf()
        with open('result.pdf', 'wb') as output:
            output.write(bytes_array)
```

Comment: i got same problem here, pdfkit works fine but when trying to add styles like `dir='rtl'` or `text-align=right` texts with combined En and Fa words will strangely change their position and overwrite each other, margins and paddings won't work either too. had you such a problem? and if yes, may you guide me with solutions?

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone wants to generate pdfs from html templates using `Django`, this is how it can be done:

```
template = get_template("app_name/template.html")
context = Context({'something':some_variable})
html = template.render(context)
pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False)
response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=output.pdf'
return response
```

Answer (score 0):

send multibyte (farsi , arabic) string as parameter to below typescript function, and put returned string to pdfMaker or any other PDF generator

```
farsiNew(farsistr){ 
         // because pdfmake display it mirrored by default
        var allText = '';
        var point = 19;
        var words = farsistr.split("\n");
        var newword;
        for(var i=0; i<=words.length-1; i++){
           newword = words[i].split( ' ');
            if (newword.length <point) {
                allText = allText + newword.reverse().join(' ') + "\n";
            }else{
 
                for(var q =0; q<= Math.ceil (newword.length / point); q++) {

                    var s , t;
                    if (q === 0) {
                        s = 0; t = point;
                    }
                    else {
                         s = q * point + q;
                        t = s + point;
                    }
                    for (var v = t; v >= s; v--) {
                        if(!newword[v])
                            continue;
                        allText = allText + ' ' +newword[v]

                    }
                   allText = allText + '\n';
                }
            }
        }
        return allText;

}
```