# How to draw arabic text on the PDF file using `drawString`correctly? (reportlab.pdfgen)

Tags: python-3.x, arabic, reportlab, arabic-support

I use python reportlab(window10, python3.6) to write text in the page, when the text is English it works, but when I use Arabic text it writes messy code in the image.

Below is my code:

```
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
page = canvas.Canvas("test.pdf", pagesize=A4)
page.drawString(10*mm, 267*mm, "اللغة العربية") 
page.showPage()
page.save()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNNtA.jpg)

Comment: Please, reformat the question to remove all those `enter code here` and to have the code nicely formatted. What you expect is also not clear.

Comment: ok, I edit style. like this edit

Comment: Maybe you can find a solution there: [How to create PDF containing Persian(Farsi) text with reportlab, rtl and bidi in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345450/how-to-create-pdf-containing-persianfarsi-text-with-reportlab-rtl-and-bidi-in)

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you must use 4 steps:

1. Import ***rtl***

```py
from rtl import reshaper
```

2. Implement this method:

```
@staticmethod
def reshape_text(text):
    text = reshaper.reshape(text)
    text = get_display(text)
    get_display() 
    return text
```

3. Add your font in pdf. I use **FPDF** library and in below I append my code

```py
import fpdf
pdf = fpdf.FPDF(format="A4")  # pdf format
pdf.add_font("fontNormal", style="", fname="./Sahel.ttf", uni=True)
pdf.set_font("fontNormal", "", size=int(10))  # font and textsize
```

4. At the end you can pass your text to the pdf generator:

```py
pdf.cell(90, 7, txt=self.reshape_text("مهندس علیرضا صفافرد"), ln=1, align="R")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a font that is supporting arabic characters. I took the font `Scheherazade` here as an example (you have to copy `Scheherazade-Regular.ttf` in `site-packages\reportlab\fonts`):

```
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont 

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Scheherazade', 'Scheherazade-Regular.ttf'))

page = canvas.Canvas("test.pdf", pagesize=A4)
page.setFont('Scheherazade', 12)
page.drawString(10*mm, 267*mm, "اللغة العربية") 
page.showPage()
page.save()
```

Ref: [Report Lab can't handle hebrew (unicode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958904/report-lab-cant-handle-hebrew-unicode)

Comment: Please expand this answer to explain what changes you've made and why. Specifically, Scheherazade-Regular is required because you need a font that includes glyphs for Arabic, and the UTF-8 encoding you've added. Otherwise future searchers need to dig through this code to figure out how it differs and guess at why. Thanks for contributing.

Comment: thank you for this answer. but it maybe I reach to my need  but not exactly the letters which output not like this "اللغة العربية" it output "ا ل غ ة   ا ل ع  ر ب ي ة" so what is the answer