# django create rtl PDF file dynamically

Tags: django, pdf, xhtml2pdf

I have tried many library to create rtl PDF file with Arabic language dynamically and I couldn't figure how work it out as all working in ltr direction but not rtl direction, any suggestions?

Comment: What do you need PDF for if you're on a website already. (And what do you need a special PDF generator for if you're using a browser that can save to PDF already.)

Comment: I have a create a property management system with django and I'm listing the lease contracts in a template so I want to print the lease contract in pdf file dynamically once the user click on any item in the list, I used (xhtml2pdf) library and it work in English ltr direction but it didn't work for Arabic rtl direction

Comment: ReportLab community edition can create RTL, also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345450/how-to-create-pdf-containing-persianfarsi-text-with-reportlab-rtl-and-bidi-in